# MySQL query on table with 23m rows very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm working on a PHP web service which needs to perform a query on a table with 23 million records. The query I've created seems to be taking 30+ seconds to complete, and from what I can tell it's the order by portion of the query that's causing the problem, as without it, the query response it fast.

Here is the query;

```
SELECT artist_feeds.*, artists.name, artists.picture AS profile_picture
FROM artist_feeds
INNER JOIN user_artists ON user_artists.artist_id = artist_feeds.artist_id
INNER JOIN artists ON artists.id = artist_feeds.artist_id
WHERE artist_feeds.feed_date >= '2015-10-01'
    AND user_artists.user_id = 486
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT id FROM user_artist_disabled_networks AS uadn
        WHERE uadn.user_id = 486
            AND uadn.artist_id = artist_feeds.artist_id
            AND uadn.socialnetwork_id = artist_feeds.socialnetwork_id
        LIMIT 1
        )
ORDER BY artist_feeds.feed_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

An explain of the query looks like this;

[image]

Can anyone provide any pointers?

As requested, SHOW CREATE TABLE output;

```
CREATE TABLE `artist_feeds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `feed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `hash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `picture` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `link` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `artist_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `socialnetwork_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `direct_link` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `is_master_feed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rss_feed_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `artist_id` (`artist_id`),
  KEY `socialnetwork_id` (`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feedidnetwork` (`feed_id`(191),`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feeddatenetworkid` (`feed_date`,`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feeddatenetworkidartistid` (`artist_id`,`socialnetwork_id`,`feed_date`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `feed_date` (`feed_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26991713 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Resolved: Thanks to a pointer from Bill, I researched being able to change the order of table access in the table so that the artist_feed table was the first table accessed, this in turn would remove the need for a filesort on the data, which leads to a speed increase.

I ended up using STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. My working query is;

```
SELECT af.*, a.name, a.picture AS profile_picture
FROM artist_feeds AS af
STRAIGHT_JOIN user_artists AS ua ON ua.artist_id = af.artist_id
STRAIGHT_JOIN artists AS a ON a.id = af.artist_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_artist_disabled_networks AS uadn
  ON uadn.user_id = ua.user_id AND uadn.socialnetwork_id = af.socialnetwork_id
WHERE af.feed_date >= '2015-10-01'
    AND uadn.user_id IS NULL
    AND ua.user_id = 498
ORDER BY af.feed_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

EXPLAIN now looks like this;

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but if you expect it to take less than a sec, add a 3 sec timeout and retry code, then start investigate.

Comment: I'm not expecting the query to take less than a second. That's how long the query appears to be taking to complete most of the time, but sometimes the query hangs and then causes a queue of queries behind it.

Comment: Please when you ask for query optimization help, post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query. It helps us understand the data types, indexes, and constraints you have defined, and this is needed to make a strategy for optimization.

Comment: Unrelated to the Question, but this is a bad index:  KEY `feedidnetwork` (`feed_id`(191),`socialnetwork_id`) -- See [_workarounds for 767 errors_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes).

Answer (score 2):

I would write the query with an exclusion join instead of a NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT af.*, a.name, a.picture AS profile_picture
FROM artist_feeds AS af
INNER JOIN user_artists AS ua ON ua.artist_id = af.artist_id
INNER JOIN artists AS a ON a.id = af.artist_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_artist_disabled_networks AS uadn
  ON uadn.user_id = ua.user_id AND uadn.socialnetwork_id = af.socialnetwork_id
WHERE af.feed_date >= '2015-10-01'
  AND ua.user_id = 486
  AND uadn.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY af.feed_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

According to the EXPLAIN, the order of table access is:

1. `ua` lookup by user_id
2. `a` lookup by PRIMARY KEY
3. `af` lookup by artist_id and range condition by feed_date
4. `uadn` lookup by user_id and socialnetwork_id

So you should have indexes:

- user_artists (user_id, artist_id)
- artists needs only its PRIMARY KEY
- artist_feeds (artist_id, feed_date)
- user_artist_disabled_networks (user_id, socialnetwork_id)

A large part of your query performance issue is undoubtedly the **Temp table, filesort**. This is unavoidable, because your query doesn't access the artist_feeds table first.

---

Re your updates in your question:

It isn't a good idea to override the optimizer's order of table access. You can see that be forcing it to read the `af` table first, now it has to examine 11.19 million entries in that table. At least it's able to avoid sorting the result manually—it can rely on the natural order of the `af` table. But I'm not sure that's a good tradeoff in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that's provided some pointers. I'll try to rewrite the query to amend the ordering of table access.

Comment: Note that the order of table access is the decision of the optimizer—it has nothing to do with the order you reference the tables in your query. The exception is when you override the optimizer using `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: Could you post  SHOW INDEX FROM artist_feeds so we can see the details, cardinality, etc?